# .NET JSON serializer seems to be rounding up values of type double up to 16 digits in some cases

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, double, system.text.json

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API that uses the .NET JSON serializer (i.e. `System.Text.Json`, Version=7.0.0.0) for serializing the API result data into a JSON response.

I've noticed that for some double values it actually rounds those to 16 digits whereas some have 17 digits - I've read the documentation from Microsoft which states that a double value can have between 15-17 digits, but I'm not sure why in some cases it decides to round it up to 16 digits (it's probably related to representation in bits etc.?)

What's even more interesting is while debugging, the double value is properly assigned like this - 6.5784774568779181 .. and then when it gets serialized into a JSON response it becomes like this - 6.578477456877918 (I have other examples like 99.999999999999986 vs 99.99999999999999)

Initially I thought it might've been my JSON serializer options which were like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o =>
    {
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        // This will add support for serializing double NaN and Infinity values to the response JSON.
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
    });
```

.. so I thought maybe the NaN and positive/negative infinity handling was probably reserving some bits or messing up with the output result, but then I've set the number handling options to `JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString` and also `JsonNumberHandling.Strict` - but getting the same result.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens - is this a bug or expected behaviour? If it is expected, is there an explanation as to why it happens as I couldn't find anything too relevant on the internet. For context, my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API consumes a legacy WCF .NET Framework service and that service is able to serialize and send the entire double value to my API.

// Edit
Maybe I haven't been clear enough in my original post. **I don't really decide whether or not to use precise numbers.** As I said, I have a legacy WCF .NET Framework service that I need to expose via a somewhat REST-full API (for hopefully obvious reasons). So my .NET 7 Web API is just a proxy of the underlying WCF service. On my .NET 7 API I have a contract/DTO that exposes a field of type double which is simply a pass through of the underlying WCF double field. Now, the WCF field yields a double value of 6.5784774568779181 .. which is correctly consumed and stored in memory (i.e. a debugging session) in my API double field, but when it gets serialized into a JSON response it becomes 6.578477456877918. The way we've picked this up is by running regressions tests that were supposed to simulate 2 similar (identical) API calls - one directly to the WCF service and one to the new Web API. Then we run the comparison on the data that we receive from the WCF service and from the Web API. In some scenarios the Web API service rounds to 16 digits - obviously, not a huge blocker, but my main question was why that is since the .NET Framework serializaiton seems more consistent.

Comment: If you need *precise* numbers, don't use floating point variables. That is a basic truth of programming.

Comment: As nvoigt said floating point numbers are, well, "floaty". Most of us learn to use ints pretty quick! Do you have to use FP? What *exactly* are you storing? Could it be stored as an int32 or int64? For example if you need xxx.xxx then store xxxxxx as an int64. In that case if you have 123456 it will serialize as "123456".

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @nvoigt - I've edited my answer to provide even more context and clarity, I don't decide whether to use floating point variables, I just consume a legacy WCF service via a .NET Web API which serve simply as a proxy (no floating point math etc. involved).

Comment: _"but I'm not sure why in some cases it decides to round it up to 16 digits"_ - I would guess that this somehow is connected to the fact that numbers in computers are represented in binary form. Imagine that you have 2 bit to represent decimal part, then you will be able to actually represent only `x.0`, `x.1`, `x.2` and `x.4` the rest of decimal parts you will need to trim/round.

Comment: @GuruStron you would actually display `x.0`, `x.25`, `x.5` and `x.75`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @JeanotZubler maybe. TBH it was a.long time since I've tried to dive deeper into float representation, the point I'm trying to show is that limited number of bits result in limited number of decimal digits you can show and number of decimal digits can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search and regarding the comments:
As you said, while you debugging double value were correctly assigned, but after serialization into a JSON response it was rounded, is related to how the serializer handles floating point precision.

Actually based on my search, double values in .NET are floating point numbers with different levels of precision that can be changed depending on how to represent them and has limitations in precision due to its binary representation.

Also, The System.Text.Json serializer has its own internal logic for handling floating numbers. When these numbers are serialized into JSON, the serializer might choose a representation that balances precision and efficiency that can lead to the observed rounding behavior like your case. It's not a bug in real but an aspect of how the serializer optimizes and standardizes data representation.

I think you can possibly do these two actions:

1- Config and adjust serializer option or custom convertors. but if you use float or double, it might happened again because the behavior is their characteristics.

**2- In my view, I would recommend this approach. if you can, use decimal instead of double. it can handle high precision and is the best fit for these situations but in big calculation might a bit performance issue compare with double but in big calculation.**

Based on my search, If you want to use approach 1 you can do like the bellow code.:

```
public class DoubleConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetDouble();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("G17")); // G17 format specifier for maximum precision
    }
}
```

in your service:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DoubleConverter());
    });
```

in your application:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<SampleModel> Get()
    {
        var model = new SampleModel
        {
            Value = 6.5784774568779181
        };

        return model;
    }
}
```

When you run this sample and enter the /sample endpoint, you might see the SampleModel JSON output with the Value property serialized using the custom DoubleConverter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Yeah, I think it's some internal behavior in the System.Text.Json serializer - it's good that we can create custom double converters, I might try this one out if needed as I don't have control over the incoming data (which is double instead of decimal). For now, we've just added some tolerance in our test cases to ignore the serialization differences between .NET framework and .NET Core (.NET 7) - but when I have some spare time I'll try the custom converter approach.

Comment: @EmanuilBoyanov That's good idea. with you the luck :)